# What does "Processing triggers" actually mean?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

Pretty much the title. I've seen it so many times and never really thought until today on what it actually does. A quick google search pulled up nothing in relation to it. An explanation would be much appreciated to get this out of my mind!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/178694/what-does-it-mean-processing-triggers-for-after-installing-uninstalling/178704

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the reply, I saw that page before and the issue is the person didn't know if they had to do anything during those messages, where the selected answer tells them they don't have to. I am looking for the actual meaning of the message, like what's going on behind it.